# Why doesn't CanCan respect my rule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I need to restrict users to only access their shipping list items by 'supplier_id '. I know I can use 'accessible_by' to add a 'where' clause. But if I forget to add the accessible_by scope to my query, in the following controller, in action index, the user can read any list.

```
class SupplierShippingListsController < ApplicationController

    load_and_authorize_resource
    def index
        @shipping_lists = SupplierShippingList.where(:supplier_id => params[:supplier_id])
        authorize! :read, SupplierShippingList
    end

end
```

I defined this rule first, hopping the instance would be checked against my hash but it doesn't, as if :supplier_id was pointless.

```
can :read, SupplierShippingList, :supplier_id => user.company_id
```

So I tried a block with a random value to make it fail the authorization, but the user can still access the action.

```
can :read, SupplierShippingList do |list|
    list.supplier_id == 17
end
```

Is there some hidden thing to set?

### EDIT

I also tried

```
authorize! :read, @shipping_lists
```

with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index actions will ignore the block, so your second example will not work. Your best bet for relatively simple abilities like this is to use a hash of conditions like your first example. But `load_and_authorize_resource` will automatically load `@supplier_shipping_lists` for you. Your index action as shown will overwrite the variable and make the 'load' portion of 'load and authorize resource' pointless. You should remove your index action and let CanCan do the loading for you. If you don't override the instance variable, you should see what you expect as long as you use the hash of conditions.

Also, you don't need to manually call `authorize!` either. That is the 'authorize' part of `load_and_authorize_resource`. You need to just let CanCan do the work. When you enter your index action, the instance variable will either already be initialized, *but will be empty if you don't have the authority to view any lists*.

Comment: What about if the @supplier_shipping_lists is empty? That is what I was having. So authorization was letting me through. Any advice?

Comment: No, if it's empty, then you don't have the authority to view any of the lists. Unlike the show action, CanCan loads the index action through the `accessible_by` scope, which will return an empty array if there is nothing that is accessible. I will update my answer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `load_and_authorize_resource` you don't have to do anything. In your index action it should find all of the `supplier_shipping_lists` that correspond to the user company if you're using the `can :read, SupplierShippingList, :supplier_id => user.company_id`. If that isn't working, do you have any other rules being applied to the `SupplierShippingList`?

Comment: There are no other rules in the ability. I am expecting to see an authorization exception for both my rules above. I see the db queries are requesting whatever :supplier_id I pass in the URL.

Comment: I removed load_and_authorize_resource and I still cannot get an exception as I expect it.

Comment: Add the `load_and_authorize_resource` back and make an empty index action `def index; end`. This will give you `@supplier_shipping_lists` that is correctly filtered.

Comment: I had an empty array! So the rule was ok since I could ':read' but the hash does not make sense if the query result is empty. Any advice on this?